# Why do dotnet command line builds fail on MVC View errors but VS2017 does not?

Tags: razor, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a .NET Core 2 MVC project in VS2017. I've noticed that when building with the command line, any C# errors in my Razor views cause the build to fail. However when building in VS2017 the build will run fine. If I have a `.cshtml` file open that contains C# errors, they will show as errors in the error list, but they won't stop the build from completing.

I'm not sure why I'm getting two different results as surely both are using MSBuild under the hood? Is there a way I get VS to fail on Razor C# errors in the same way as the command line does?

Comment: Are you using the same target (release/debug) in both the command line and VS?

Comment: Ah of course, I'm building in Release mode from the command line. It would still be useful to see those messages in Debug mode, is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure. It may be possible but it would probably slow your build a little bit. I looked here for reference: [View Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think I understand what's going on. Razor views are only compiled on Publish, not on build. It doesn't look like it's possible to do it on build right now.

Comment: I've checked my build scripts too, looks like my build script was doing a publish too, hence the messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ASP.NET Core 2.x Razor, views can be precompiled on publish if the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation` package is included (setting the `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` to true is optional). It is not currently possible to compile views as part of a standard debug build.

For further details see [Razor view compilation and precompilation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

> If your project targets .NET Framework, include a package reference to
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation:
>
> ```xml
> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
> ```
>
> Prepare the app for a framework-dependent deployment by executing a
>   command such as the following at the project root:
>
> ```
> > dotnet publish -c Release
> ```
>
> A *.PrecompiledViews.dll* file, containing the compiled
>   Razor views, is produced when precompilation succeeds.